# Add a warning message when a button is pressed

Tags: ios, uibutton, action, warnings

I am currently coding a game for IOS 7 on Xcode 5 and I am adding a "reset" button to the View Controller than resets the game and score to 0.

I would like to ask the user if they are sure they want to restart. How is this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a `UIAlertView` to ask the user. Make sure that your `UIViewController` confirms to the `UIAlertViewDelegate` protocol.

**ViewController.h**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>
```

**ViewController.m**

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Restart" message:@"Do you really want to restart?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Restart", nil];
[alert show];

...

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        //cancel
    } else if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        //restart
    }
}
```

Comment: is the method alertView: clickedButtonAtIndex: the action I am creating or is it just a new method that I add to the implementation? I already have the logic behind the restart as an action once the reset button is pressed.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it successfully implemented. Thanks for your help